# Docker for Mac uses disk space when containers start

Tags: macos, docker, macos-catalina

My disk image is 128GB with an "on disk" size of 101.7GB. Each time I restart any containers, an additional .2GB is added to my on disk size. I've already had to increase the disk image up to 128GB, and soon that will be consumed as well.

Another developer who uses the same Dockerfiles I am (we both work on the same projects) is not having this problem.

```
Docker: 19.03.2
macOS: 10.15 (Catalina)
```

Comment: Should be APFS-- if so perhaps it's local snapshots?   Also what platform is the other dev using?

Comment: How do I confirm whether it's APFS? Other dev is on macOS El Capitan I believe. I can verify tomorrow the exact version, but definitely macOS.

Comment: He's on 10.12 and running the same Docker version as me.

Comment: macOS 10.12 uses HFS by default.  It could be local snapshots causing the problem as 10.15 has time machine automatically create them.  Prob due to the the way APFS can easily handle 'new versions' of files.  What happens if you use an external HFS drive, copy some containers over, and try the same thing?  Also check this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314038/apfs-high-sierra-tmutil-deletelocalsnapshots-not-deleting-snapshots

Comment: I don't use Time Machine and running `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` per that thread shows no results. My external is a SATA drive. Can I create an HFS partition on it or on my laptop's drive, or would I need to do a format? Thank you for your help.

Comment: TM runs by default now to manage local snapshots on APFS.  Have you tried reading this link?  https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/space/

Comment: I just read through it and all of those steps I have already tried prior to posting this question. My primary concern atm is why does the "Size on disk" value increase each time I start containers? I think you're saying it has to do with TM creating local snapshots on the fly?